# Events not firing after extending a custom backbone view

Tags: backbone.js, typescript

What's the correct way to have both events from the parent and child views be registered properly and fire?

With this approach the praent's events events wipe out the child's. I've also tried to pass in the child's events as part of the `options` to the parent, and then have the parent extend them before registering but then the parent's events no longer work.

Parent

```
// this is helpers/authorization/views/authHelper
export class AuthView extends Backbone.View {
    constructor(options?) {
        this.events = {
            'keypress #auth': 'setAuthorizationCodeKeypress',
            'click .create': 'setAuthorizationCode'
        };
        super(options);
    }
}
```

Child

```
import AV = module("helpers/authorization/views/authHelper")
export class PageHelperView extends AV.AuthView {
    constructor(options?) {
        this.events = {
            'click .configHead': 'toggle'
        }
        super(options);
    }
}
```

I'd prefer them to share the same element and only require a call to `new EHV.EncoderAPIHelperView().render();` to render them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete working solution:

**Parent view:**

```
export class AuthView extends Backbone.View {

    constructor(options?) {
        this.events = {
            'keypress #auth': 'setAuthorizationCodeKeypress',
            'click .create': 'setAuthorizationCode'
        };

        super(options);
    }
}
```

**Child view:**

```
import AV = module("helpers/authorization/views/authHelper")
export class PageHelperView extends AV.AuthView {

    constructor(options?) {
        super(options);
    }

    initialize(options) {
        this.events = _.extend(this.events, {
            'click .configHead': 'toggle'
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: edited with probably better answer

You can declare parent events directly inside the object, by doing that, you won't have to create new constructor. Parent view would look like this:

```
export class AuthView extends Backbone.View {
    events = {
        'keypress #auth': 'setAuthorizationCodeKeypress',
        'click .create': 'setAuthorizationCode'        
    }
}
```

Now you can rewrite child to this:

```
import AV = module("helpers/authorization/views/authHelper")
export class PageHelperView extends AV.AuthView {
    initialize(options?) {
        this.events = {
            'click .configHead': 'toggle'
        }        
    }
}
```

**_.extend** call add missing entries to events and replace entries that share keys. (see more [here](http://underscorejs.org/#extend))

Also, I'm not really great with typescript, so there might be a problem or two with this code.

Comment: Have you tested this? For me, this only works if you add a call to `this.delegateEvents();` after the extend. Thanks

Comment: @ryan Place this in the `initialize` method. `initialize` is called before `delegateEvents` (which is called in the constructor). So here `delegateEvents` is called before `this.events` is extended.

Comment: no, not really tested, so you are probably right, also I agree that initialize would be better method to use